# How to arrange testlists as we needed order in telerik test studio

Tags: testing, telerik, telerik-test-studio

My test list is

1. Vendor
2. Employee
3. customer
4. Initial Navigation

I want to display like

1. Initial Navigation first then
2. customer
3. vendor
4. Employee.

How can I arrange in this order.am not asking about tests in the test list.test list itself
need to re arrange

Comment: are you saying you've got four lists that you want to arrange in a specific order?

Comment: Thank you Steven for giving reply, Yes i want arrange the specific order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid displaying the list of Test Lists, like many other grids, can be sorted by any column by clicking on the column header. You could give the items alphabetical names then sort by the name column.

[image: screenshot of Test List grid]

I do not know of any way to otherwise specify a particular order of display.

If this is a feature you'd like to request, http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/117/ is a good place to do so. Please be sure to include some information on how and why you'd use this feature so that it can be properly prioritized.

Comment: Thanks again Steven , is it possible without numbering...?

Comment: it's just sorting the column alphabetically, so you could call them "a list" "b list" etc.  I just used numbers to make it obvious.